# Can't index link.title and link.description because "link" seems to name conflict with something in Thinking Sphin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, thinking-sphinx

I have the following define_index method:

define_index do
    indexes content
    indexes tags.content, :as => :tag_content
    indexes link.title

```
has :is_private
has :user_id
has :created_at
```

end

When I index I get the following error:
WARNING: Global access to Rake DSL methods is deprecated.  Please include
    ...  Rake::DSL into classes and modules which use the Rake DSL methods.
WARNING: DSL method ThinkingSphinx::Index::Builder#link called at /Users/azamtaghipoor/pakrat/Pakrat/app/models/user_post.rb:64:in `block in '
rake aborted!
wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)

I've already tried :link, :link:title :link.title and similar variations

without the indexes link.title all works fine.
Any help would be much appreciated
Thanks,
Soheil

Answer (score 0):

found the answer:

```
indexes assoc(:link).title, :as => :link_title
```

from https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/thinking-sphinx/aLkuwVzJSgg 
problem asnwered by pat allen: indexes link.title causes error due to name conflict with some thinking sphinx method